# Return existing record rather than creating Rest API framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

In my API, I have a create view tied that references another record OneToOne. However, occasionally it seems that users send through two requests at once and the second fails due to a duplicate record clash:

```
class CreateProfileLink(generics.CreateAPIView):

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        ins = serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    serializer_class = ProfileLinkSerializer
```

Is there a way I could override the create method to return the record if it already exists rather than creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in your serializer class, by overriding its [`create()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) method:

```
class ProfileLinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile, _ = Profile.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        return profile
```

Since you haven't provided your `models.py`, I am using `Profile` as a model name here. Make sure to replace it if it is different in your project.